# Number of queries executed over psycopg2 connection

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I would like to know the number of sql queries which were executed on a psycopg2 connection.

Is there a way to get this number?

I would like to warn if a http request produces too many statements.

I am running a django application. If DEBUG is True, then I have [connection.queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running). But I would like to get this value from a production server

**Update**

I want numbers (statistics) from the prod environment. This question is not about debugging a particular http request.

Comment: Did you try `Django Debug Toolbar`? It shows the number of executed queries.

Comment: @Chiefir I want to get the number for each http request on the production machine. The django debug toolbar registers a signal handler to do its job. I would like to avoid this overhead, since I am afraid that the django debug toolbar would decrease performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [django-silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk). It is a profiling tool that records metrics like response times and the number of queries.

If you want to roll you own solution and you are using Django 2.0, you can create a middleware with a [connection wrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/instrumentation/). The documentation even showcases a `QueryLogger` class:

```
import time
from django.db import connection


class QueryLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queries = []

    def __call__(self, execute, sql, params, many, context):
        current_query = {'sql': sql, 'params': params, 'many': many}
        start = time.time()
        try:
            result = execute(sql, params, many, context)
        except Exception as e:
            current_query['status'] = 'error'
            current_query['exception'] = e
            raise
        else:
            current_query['status'] = 'ok'
            return result
        finally:
            duration = time.time() - start
            current_query['duration'] = duration
            self.queries.append(current_query)


class QueryLogginMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        ql = QueryLogger()
        with connection.execute_wrapper(ql):
            response = self.get_response(request)

        # do something with ql.queries here

        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount of queries made on Production and Development are the same, if you have the same environment on your database and everything else.

I recommend you to use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io) as mentioned, copy see about how many queries your View are doing and rethink your code based on that, if you want to see about those queries performance i recommend you to use the `explain` command from postgresql.

I usually, copy the query and paste it with explain inside my postgreaql database shell. See this: http://recordit.co/rGZ2SAo7PX

Comment: You are right, if I do the exactly same request on the same data set in dev, then the amount of queries will be equal. But I want statistics from the prod environment. I can't reproduce a month of prod traffic in a dev environment. I updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: In this case, there are a few tools that you can use, the easier to install and use its https://newrelic.com
Depending on your trafic and environment it can be expensive but it totally worth it in my point of view.